# How to calculate a summation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I'd like to know the answer of 
ab+(a+1)(b+1)+(a+2)(b+2)+...+(a+M)(b+M)

Is there anyone who know it? 
Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is a start: 
$$
(a+k)(b+k)=ab+(a+b)k+k^2
$$
Thus you may split your sum up as 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^M(a+k)(b+k)&=\sum_{k=0}^M(ab+(a+b)k+k^2)\\&=\left(\sum_{k=0}^Mab\right)+(a+b)\left(\sum_{k=0}^Mk\right)+\left(\sum_{k=0}^Mk^2\right )
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

First notice that $(a+n)(b+n)=ab+n(a+b)+n^2$ for every $n$. So every term in your sum can be split in this manner, and then changing the order of summation gives
\begin{align*}
&ab+(a+1)(b+1)+(a+2)(b+2)+\cdots+(a+M)(b+M)\\
=&ab+\big(ab+1(a+b)+1^2\big)+\big(ab+2(a+b)+2^2\big)+\cdots+\big(ab+M(a+b)+M^2\big)\\
=&ab(M+1)+(a+b)(1+2+\cdots+M)+(1^2+2^2+\cdots+M^2).
\end{align*}
For the sake of simplifying this you could use the formulas
$$
1+2+\cdots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\ ,\ \ \ \ 1^2+2^2+\cdots+n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}, 
$$
and then conclude that your sum is equal to
$$
ab(M+1)+(a+b)\cdot\frac{M(M+1)}{2}+\frac{M(M+1)(2M+1)}{6}.
$$

Comment: That's it! Thanks